Is there an equivalent to Harvard Sentences in Chinese?
The Harvard sentences - Wikipedia are 72 lists of 10 English sentences that:

Are phonetically balanced in the sense that the phonemes that are used in the sentences appear at the same frequency they do in English.
Contain all phonemes that appear in English.

Here are a few examples of them:

Oak is strong and also gives shade.
Cats and dogs each hate the other.
The pipe began to rust while new.
Open the crate but don't break the glass.

Question: Is there an equivalent of the Harvard sentences for Chinese, i.e. a phonetically balanced collection of Chinese sentences containing all phonemes used in Chinese?

The Harvard sentences, or Harvard lines, is a collection of 720 sample phrases,.....They are phonetically balanced sentences that use specific phonemes at the same frequency they appear in English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_sentences

Although I do not know if there is a Chinese equivalent to the Harvard Sentences. I encourage you to find and use any of the sentences (句子) and phrases (短语) in any of the elementary Chinese textbook, they are straightforward enough. My tip is to focus on the Subject, Predicate, Object (主谓宾) of the sentences as a starter. Then follow with the phonemes.
I also found that the University of Washington Modern Chinese syllable chart that you look into, it has the consonants, vowels, and finals of Mandarin Syllables:
https://courses.washington.edu/chin342/ipa/about.html
Other than there, there are charts that you could find online.
